# unwanted content dropping under image

Tags: html, css

I have text next to a image (red square for now).
When i make the window really small then the text goes under the image, i don't want this ever to happen.

so good:

[image]

bad:

[image]

How can this be prevended?

```
<div class="entrie">
                <img class="entrieImage" src="images/img01.png"/>

                <div class="entrieInfo">
                    <div class="band">Green</div>
                    <div class="album">...</div>
                    <div class="label">ATCO</div>
                    <div class="year">1966</div>
                    -
                    <div class="tags">rousseau, green, woodsy, band photo, 12IN, tree, civilization, Atco, 1960's, Fuzz
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

-

```
.entrie {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.entrieInfo {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: -45px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

}

.entrieImage {
    /* if you only set the width then the height will be set automaticly proportional*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
}
```

here a js fiddle for easy testing:

http://jsfiddle.net/K4RFU/

Comment: What *do* you want to happen when the window gets too small? Show scrollbars? Make the image smaller? Hide the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a `min-width` on `.entrie` which is sufficiently large to encompass its content.